# Improve the loss reduction in a neural network model

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

The following code is to train a neural network model of a given dataset (50,000 samples, 64 dim).

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam


X, y = process_dataset()
model = Sequential([
    Dense(16, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu'),
    Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

'''
    Compile the Model
'''
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])

'''
    Fit the Model
'''
model.fit(X, y, shuffle=True, epochs=1000, batch_size=200, validation_split=0.2, verbose=2)
```

In the beginning, you can see below that the `val_loss` gets reduced from one epoch to another very well.

```
Epoch 82/1000
 - 0s - loss: 0.2036 - acc: 0.9144 - val_loss: 0.2400 - val_acc: 0.8885
Epoch 83/1000
 - 0s - loss: 0.2036 - acc: 0.9146 - val_loss: 0.2375 - val_acc: 0.8901
```

When the model takes many epochs, the loss change becomes so small, especially when the number of epochs increases.

```
Epoch 455/1000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0903 - acc: 0.9630 - val_loss: 0.1317 - val_acc: 0.9417
Epoch 456/1000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0913 - acc: 0.9628 - val_loss: 0.1329 - val_acc: 0.9443
```

Kindly, I have two questions:

1. What does this phenomenon mean? i.e., the loss begins to decrease very well at the beginning but not much reduction by the time the training epochs takes a lot of iteration.
2. What is the possible solution for this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the gradients of the weights converging at a local (or perhaps global) minimum. Some reasons this may occur are because:

- a) The learning rate is too small
- b) The model is not able to successfully classify your data any further than it already has, which means the data may be bad and needs further pre-processing

Here is a more in depth explanation: [Convergence of neural network weights](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65877/convergence-of-neural-network-weights)

Some solutions would be to try grid searching on your hyper parameters such as learning rate, number of neurons in each layer, number of layers etc.